# Reading a complete packet asychronously suing System.IO.Stream.ReadAsync()

Tags: c#, asynchronous, bluetooth, async-await, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a C# `async` function from `FromStream` that I am trying to read from a `Bluetooth LE` stream.

```
  public static async Task<MySerialPacket> FromStream(Stream stream, HashComputingFunc computeHash, IMyMessageFactory factory)
        {
            var packet = new MySerialPacket(computeHash);

            packet.m_header = await MySerialHeader.FromStream(stream, computeHash);

            var b = new byte[packet.m_header.DataLength];

            var bytes_read = await stream.ReadAsync(b, 0, packet.m_header.DataLength); 


            packet.VerifyCheckSum(b, "Data");

            var count = b[0];

            if (count > 0)
            {
                var lengths = new short[count];

                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    lengths[i] = (short)(b[1 + i * 2] | b[2 + i * 2] >> 8);
                }

                var startByte = 1 + 2 * count;

                for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    var m = b.Skip(startByte).Take(lengths[i]).ToArray();
                    packet.Message = factory.FromBytes(m);
                }
            }

            return packet;
        }
```

`ReadAsync` currently returns a non-zero number of bytes that is less than or equal to `DataLength` (bytes requested).

As you can see I need the `DataLength` bytes for a well formed packet.What is a sensible way to handle this problem. Does C# framework provide any functions to handle this scenario. I would ideally prefer a non-blocking way.

Comment: @Noseratio - Can you please have a look at this question ? thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looking for a framework function... why not use looping calls to ReadAsync until you get `DataLength` bytes read? You would only need to change the 0 parameter in the call with the total bytes you have read so far.

Comment: Y - I am thinking there should be a better way, though I am not sure. What you are suggesting is essentially blocking till you get necessary bytes.

Comment: Well, maybe there is a better way, but having several calls to **ReadAsync** inside **FromStream** shouldn't block the method calling **FromStream** unless you reach the point where you need to await the Task<MySerialPacket> returned by **FromStream**